# Unmarshall JSON into a Generic Struct

Tags: json, go, generics

I have a JSON endpoint that can changes the data type of one of its fields where it varies from string to map and I don't have a way to what it will be ahead of time.

I was looking to use Generic, but the code I have managed to write, requires me to know the data type ahead of time.  See blow.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type MapOrStringType interface {
    map[string]string | *string
}

type Foobar[T MapOrStringType] struct {
    Test T `json:"test"`
    //Samir *string
}

func main() {
    someString := "moo"
    s := Foobar[map[string]string]{ }
    v := Foobar[*string]{}
    rawJson := `
      {
        "Test": "Hello"
      }
    `
    rawJson = `
      {
        "Test": {
           "type": "elasticsearch",
           "uid": "VuEGTpa7k"
        }
      }
    `
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(rawJson), &s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("fail")
    }


}
```

As you can see below, if I need to know the data type when instantiating the struct it seems to me like generics won't be a good fit for me.  Is there another pattern I could use or are interface{} the best path?

I was thinking of custom serializer but I don't think that will solve anything since the construct of the struct happens before hand.

**UPDATE**: Multiple people answered this in the comments, but my attempt to use generics wasn't correct.  Interface{} is the way to go since generics needs to know the type at compile time.

Comment: " it seems to me like generics won't be a good fit for me" exactly. Its user defined parametric polymorphism and if you do not know the parameter in "parametric" it doesn't help.

Comment: The type parameters must be known at compile time, because that is when generics are processed. They are not generic at runtime, when you would be unmarshaling JSON.